# Chart rendering too slow

Tags: reporting-services, charts

I have a report containing 6 charts each displaying some percentages over an interval of time.

I have put all the 6 charts in a separate RDL file and using it as a sub-report in my main report which also contains a matrix.

The issue I am facing is the chart becomes too slow (>10 s of rendering) as soon as I implement the drill down functionality. Without drill down its about 1 s.

The drill down report parameters do not have any functions - I have already converted all of them to either fields or parameters.

Its not that big of an issue yet - but we have some major changes coming to the report which may increase the number of charts to about 15 - and all of them will contain drill down action. Once that's implemented the report will definitely take more than 30 s which would not be acceptable.

Any pointers would certainly help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Drill downs can add a huge amount of output to a report, depending on the number and complexity of them.  I've seen that each drill down in our reports adds about 2K to the size of the rendered report.  Depending on how you added the drill down to the chart, every single point could be a separate link, and these add up fast.

1. Run the report without drill downs, and export it to .MHTML.
2. Run the report with the drill downs, and export it to .MHTML.
3. Compare the size of the outputs.

The reason for .MHTML output is that one file contains everything.  The file sizes should help you do the arithmetic with regards to the number of drill in your reports and help you reduce it to an appropriate amount.

Comment: Each single point plotted on the chart is indeed a link - the drill down report accepts 6 parameters. The mhtml file is more than double the size with the drill down present. The problem is I cannot reduce the number of drill downs as each one of the points in the chart needs to be drilled down.

Comment: I feel your pain.  We've had to redesign drill downs to add additional steps for users (a bad thing) to improve performance (a good thing).  Good luck.